# How does linq concat work under the hood?

Tags: c#, linq

I am considering replacing code looking like this:

```
        foreach (var meshCut in meshCuts0)
        {
            ComputePolygons(meshCut, polygons);
        }
        foreach (var meshCut in meshCuts1)
        {
            ComputePolygons(meshCut, polygons);
        }
```

With linq looking like this:

```
        meshCuts0.Concat(meshCuts1).ForEach(m => ComputePolygons(m, polygons));
```

I do not know how linq is implemented so I am not sure about the performance consequences. I would appreciate some help please.

1)

Will Concat create a list copy or is it just an enumerator doing something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
    {
        foreach (var t in a)
        {
            yield return t;
        }
        foreach (var t in b)
        {
            yield return t;
        }
    }
```

2)

Will this be the same behaviour on Mono?

3)

Is there any reference explaining how linq api functions are implemented for the performance conscious?

thanks!

**Edit**

Ok there is no ForEach so just assume I also define something like this:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach(T item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

The real question is whether Concat would be a costly overhead just for slimming down the code which thanks to the comments, I now understand it is not.

**Edit 2**

Ah, Jon Skeet suggests not adding ForEach... so I won't!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Any reason you can't test this yourself?

Comment: There's no `ForEach` extension in Linq. There is one standard instance method on `List<>` from the old .NET 2.0 days. But as soon as you've used `.Concat` from Linq, you don't have a `List<>`, so how could your question even make sense?

Comment: You: _1) Will Concat create a list copy or is it just an enumerator doing something like this [...]_ Yes, `Concat` is exactly equivalent to that.

Comment: @ash I'm asking how its implemented not whether it produces the same result.

Comment: @jeppe Thanks. Good point about the ForEach. I see its in the MoreLinq extensions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, your code would only work if you *also* introduce a `ForEach` extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`. I suggest you don't do that - see [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for the reasons I agree with.

I suggest you write it as:

```
foreach (var meshCut in meshCuts0.Concat(meshCuts1))
{
    ComputePolygons(meshCut, polygons);
}
```

`Concat` performs fine - it just iterates over the first sequence then the second, yielding items as it goes. It *doesn't* buffer all the elements. There's a very slight performance penalty for the extra level of indirection you're adding, but that's about all.

I'd expect Mono to behave the same way - `Concat` is *very* simple. In fact, as Mono is open source, you can [check it for yourself](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#L584). (It may move over time, of course...)

A while ago I blogged about LINQ to Objects in detail, reimplementing the whole thing from scratch and documenting various aspects of its performance, including where there's room for improvement. See my [Edulinq blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Only saw this after I did indeed add the extension method to the question.

Comment: As a style question, if you have a few of these type of passages of code, do you prefer multiple foreaches or using concat?

Comment: @daw: I'd probably use `Concat`... possibly with an extra local variable, e.g. `var allCuts = meshCuts0.Concat(meshCuts1); foreach (var meshCut in allCuts) ...`

Comment: Off-topic: On [your blog post on reimplementing the `Enumerable.Empty` static method](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/24/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-5-empty.aspx) you discuss carefully the fact that the same instance is returned each time (a cache). Almost two years later a new version of .NET was released, and in the document [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx) (see last part of section _Data_) a change with "compatibility issues" in the `Empty` method is listed. How shall we understand this?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That's odd... I thought it had *always* behaved that way.

Answer (score 5):

This is how linq concat works under the hood.

Microsoft .net framework 4.0:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return ConcatIterator<TSource>(first, second); 
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) { 
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element; 
}
```

Mono (source: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs#L584 )

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    Check.FirstAndSecond (first, second);

    return CreateConcatIterator (first, second);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> CreateConcatIterator<TSource> (IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
{
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second)
        yield return element;
}
```

Specific answers:

1. It's not creating any copy, it's just enumerating.
2. Yes.
3. For the performance conscious, the source code is the best.

Answer (score 1):

1. It works just like you have described it. You can download nice free tool named [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) - .net decompiler. You can load every assembly, even standart assemblies to decompiler and get source code. If you look to assembly System.Core, namespace System.Linq, class Enumerable you can see this:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
       if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
       if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
       return ConcatIterator<TSource>(first, second); 
   }

   static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) { 
       foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
       foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element; 
   }
   ```

   Talking about LINQ - it's lazy and every linq extension method uses defered calculations. There is nice guy Jon Skeet, he have a blog. There many articles named "Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part " and all of them can be found by tag 'linq': [link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/LINQ/default.aspx)
2. Mono is opensource project. You can found sources at the [github](https://github.com/mono). Class Enumerable can be founded here: [link](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs). And source code of Concat:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource> (this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
   {
       Check.FirstAndSecond (first, second);

       return CreateConcatIterator (first, second);
   }

   static IEnumerable<TSource> CreateConcatIterator<TSource> (IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second)
   {
       foreach (TSource element in first)
           yield return element;
       foreach (TSource element in second)
           yield return element;
   }
   ```